# Python command to get the bone an object is parented to

Tags: python, scripting, armature

Assuming an object is parented to an armature and one of its bones. (Type 'bone')

How to get the name of this bone using Python script?

Thanks in advance!

(Blender 3.3 User)

Comment: `bpy.context.object.parent_bone` - if obj is active. You may want to activate the tooltips (Preferences >Interface > User Tooltips) to see python details with mouseover an element.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's correct, found it now also in the blender python docs under 'Object(ID)'.